# ¿Cómo actualzar solo algunos campos de la entidad usando el metodo save() de JpaRepository?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, update, microservices

Tengo el siguiente método en el Controller para actualizar algunos campos de la entidad **Control**

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public void actualizarControl(
        @RequestBody ControlEntity entidad,  @PathVariable("id") String id) throws Exception {
    try {
        controlService.updateControl(entidad, id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error in Values ");
        throw e;
    }

}
```

y en mi servicio ocupo el metodo **save()** para realizar el update

```
    @Override
    public void updateControl(ControlEntity entidad, String id) {
        try {
            
            ControlEntity exec = new ControlEntity();
            exec.setCveEstado(entidad.getCveEstado());
            exec.setDescripcion("prueba");
            exec.setHora(entidad.getHora());
            exec.setHoraInicio("01/01/00 12:04:00.000000000");
            exec.setProcess("0");
            exec.setEsManual("0");
            exec.setFechaInicio(entidad.getFechaInicio());
            
            exec.setId(id);
            
            repository.save(exec);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("An error ocurred looking for Data");

        }

    }
```

Pero el problema es que me hace actualizar todos los campos de la entidad, y no de todos recibo datos para su actualización, solo de los campos (cveEstado, hora y fechaInicio), y del campo fechaInicio puede recibir valores **null**,  los demas campos  los quiero mantener con el valor que ya traen, pero no se como hacer para setearles su valor original.

Tengo el siguiente método que regresa la lista de lo que hay en la tabla **Control**, pero no se como mandarlo a llamar a mi metodo de **Update**, para llenar los demas campos con su valor original

```
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<?> getControl() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        List<ControlEntity> query = new ArrayList<ControlEntity>();
        try {
            query = repository.consulta();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("An error ocurred looking for Data");
            response.put("success", false);
            response.put("error", e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        response.put("success", true);
        response.put("data", query);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

y el query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT C.ID, EST.DESCRIPCION, C.HORA, C.HORA_INICIO, C.PROCESS, C.ESMANUAL, C.FECHA_INICIO FROM CONTROL 
      C INNER JOIN ESTADO EST ON C.CVE_ESTADO = EST.CVE_ESTADO", nativeQuery = true)
  List<ControlEntity> consulta();
```

como le puedo hacer para llenar los campos con su valor original de la consulta, al momento de hacer el update con los campos que si reciben un valor nuevo ?

Comment: Y en vez de crear una entidad nueva, por qué no la buscas primero, le actualizas los campos que quieres y luego la guardas?

Comment: @Benito-B cómo seria?

Comment: en vez de  = new ControlEntity() un findbyid

Comment: Te recomiendo buscar en internet ya que hay bastante documentación oficial al respecto, aquí un ejemplo: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-partial-update#load-and-save-approach